# FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate() fails with 'TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS' for some users

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

My code uses Remote Config to check for app updates as follows:

```
    ForceUpdateChecker.with(this).onUpdateNeeded(this).check();

    final FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

    // set in-app defaults
    Map<String, Object> remoteConfigDefaults = new HashMap();
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED, false);
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_CURRENT_VERSION, "2.00.229");
    remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_URL,
            "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chiaramail.pento");

    firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(remoteConfigDefaults);
    firebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate() // fetch config from server and activate
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FirebaseRemoteConfig fetched");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FirebaseRemoteConfig error:" + task.getResult());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Since I've updated the release containing this code, several users have crashed with the result 'TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS'. I believe I've looked at all the SO posts that relate to this problem, but none of them are using fetchAndActivate(). Also, I only have about 1200 users at this point, so hopefully the number of fetches isn't the problem; besides, as I understand it, Remote Config was built to push changes out to one's entire user base, so 1200 users (perhaps up to 6000 devices, max) should not be a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to this code? How do you know? A quick web search suggests TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS is an error that comes from FCM, not Remote Config.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know, and yet that's what Firebase returns in the crash report email. In the meantime, I gave up on using Remote Config for app updates and am now trying to implement it with the Google APIs, also without much success. I may be posting another question, if a search doesn't reveal anything.